# Get request Initiator stack in Network tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Each request in the "Network" tab of the dev tools has an "Initiator" column.

For AJAX requests this is mostly useless since jQuery does all of the actual requesting and ends up in here.

I vaguely read something in Google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/network) about how the Initiator object actually contains a stack trace ... So: how can I get that?

Answer (score 12):

Late answer for this, but if you hover over the link for the Initiator the stack pops up in a hover. If you carefully navigate into the popup you can click to the source lines of calls further up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link as well. It might help !

"hold Shift and hover over the request in the Requests table."

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation