# Chrome Developer Tools to determine where in code a REST call executed?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome, debugging

I've recently been put on front-end duty, and find myself a little out of my element in terms of the functionality of the Chrome Developer Tools. I tried a little google'ing but didn't find an answer to the following:

Is there some way to determine where among my open `JavaScript` sources a `REST`-call originated/executed from?

Like, is there some way to obtain the file/line (or both) that can point me to where the `GET`/`POST`/whatever command was fired?

Comment: If you are gonna use any library(jQuery, etc.) to those request, I think it's very difficult to get that data. If not, the network tab has a 'Initiator' column that should tell you the origin of the request I guess.

Comment: Yeah, there's sadly jQuery involved so I don't think that'll work for me in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug the rest api calls in chrome's network tab and also filter the request as per the status code and you can also check the headers as well as the request parameters that you are sending with request.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Guess this question was already asked but in a different way in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726402/get-request-initiator-stack-in-network-tab)

As per the linked question, we just need to hover over the link in the Initiator section of the Network tab, and it shows the complete stack, from which it should be easy to get the line number :) Tried it and it is working.